# Diesel motor running slightly jerky on normal RPM after having the turbo repaired

Tags: diesel, turbocharger, peugeot

I got my turbo repaired, the service told me that stopped working due to a sensor that had to be changed. It costed me a lot because they told me that the sensor was inside the turbo and it was hard to change.

After complaining about the car not running smoothly on lower RPM, they changed two solenoid valves which were not closing or opening properly. Still after this I get the same behaviour that is describe in detail below.

The car in **not running smoothly at normal driving RPM**, if I accelerate more I don't fill the **jerkiness**, which by the way is **not continuous, but repeats regularly about avery 3-5 seconds**,can be easily observed by driver and it is clearly more visible if the car is going up towards a hill.

If I'm thinking more, I quite similar with whats happening when you try the wrong gear.

Car details: Peugeot 307 2.0HDi / 2004, 95.000km.

Answer (score 3):

They may have replaced the vacuum solenoids but it sounds like the wastegate still isn't opening smoothly. If you can see the wastegate, apply vacuum slowly to the vacuum line and see if it moves smoothly through it's motion, especially when initially opening. If not, it probably still needs cleaning.

Under acceleration it needs the boost, but under constant drive it should be opening and closing that a tiny bit as it runs but if it can't it will increase vacuum, then it snaps open, dumps boost, then releases vacuum.

Comment: I'm not a mechanic, but I will print this and give it to my new service guys. Do you think it could also be related to the injectors and be just a coincidence that I got this after having the turbo repaired? Does it makes sense to check the injectors? (the CPU does not report any problem with them).

Comment: I am not familiar with the Peugot 2.0 HDi engine, but it sounds more like a turbo or vacuum leak than an injector issue. Some turbos use vacuum to close the wastegate and some use it to open it. But if it's bucking like that, especially after turbo work, that's where I would start. On a cold engine with a hand vacuum pump it's only a 5 minute check.